# -dealloc method not called when owning array dealloc'd... should it?

Tags: objective-c, release, new-operator, init, alloc

Here are two pieces of Objective-C code in a Foundation app. This piece of code is in a function:

```
    [arrayOfObjects addObject:[[TheShape alloc] init]];
    NSLog(@"%@", arrayOfObjects); // log verifies "<TheShape..." is in the array
    [arrayOfObjects release];
```

and in my TheShape class, I have this `dealloc` override method:

```
    - (void)dealloc {
        NSLog(@"TheShape dealloc called.");
        [super dealloc];
    }
```

Although my program works otherwise, it doesn't work the way I expect it to. When the `[arrayOfObjects release]` message is sent, I expect to see the "TheShape dealloc..." string appear in the log. It doesn't.

Q1: Why not?

So I dig a bit and simplify things. If I do something simpler like this:

```
    TheShape *aShape = [[TheShape alloc] init];
    [aShape release];
```

the debug message still doesn't appear in the log.

Q2: Why not?

But if I do this:

```
    TheShape *aShape = [TheShape new];
    [aShape release];
```

the debug message *does* appear in the log. The debug message also appears in the log if I change the alloc/init in the first sample to `new`, too.

Q3: Why?

Obviously, I'm missing something conceptual in the alloc/init/release cycle (Q's 1 and 2) and in the supposed equivalency of `new` and `alloc/init` (Q3). Can anybody point me to a tutorial that explains things a bit more for the hard of thinking, like me?

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: There should be no difference between `TheShape *aShape = [[TheShape alloc] init];` and `TheShape *aShape = [TheShape new];`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By any chance did you override `+new` on your class? It should be doing precisely the same thing as `+alloc/-init`.

In any case, your very first line

```
[arrayOfObjects addObject:[[TheShape alloc] init]];
```

is leaking your `TheShape` instance. You should turn that in to

```
[arrayOfObjects addObject:[[[TheShape alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

Comment: I didn't override the +new class, but I could see where that would be a problem if I had. I expected new to act exactly as alloc/init did, but it doesn't for some odd reason. I still wonder about that.<br> Making the TheShape autorelease does the trick, though. What is happening in the first instance? Yes, I alloc/init, so own the object, but doesn't the arrayOfObjects end up having to keep track of it for me? This is one of those cases where I clearly think one thing should happen and the Cardinal Rulez of Objective-C Memory Management seem to be at odds. Clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The array isn't "taking over" your ownership of the object. It's adding its own ownership. An object can be owned by multiple other objects. In this case, the array owned it, but so did your local method. You need to drop your ownership of it after the array picks it up.

Comment: Ah, zneak (below) answered that for me. (Pays to read ahead, I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for the `dealloc` method to be called: your object still has a non-zero reference count.

Whenever you create an object, it begins its existence with a reference count of 1. Once this count reaches 0, it is deallocated. There are specific rules for memory management that help us all stay sane. These rules speak of 'object ownership'.

Basically, you become the owner of an object if you meet one of these conditions:

- You call `retain` on the object;
- You obtain an object by calling `copy` or `mutableCopy` on another one;
- **You call the `alloc` method on an objet.**

Whenever you own an object, **you are responsible for releasing once you don't need it anymore**. It will be deleted only once no one needs it anymore.

In your snippet, **you** create the object that you pass to your array. Your array begins to use it, so it calls `retain` on it (so it stays alive while it's being held). However, once you `release` the array, your object still needs to be release by **you**, since you called the `alloc` method.

---

**EDIT** The simple snippet:

```
TheShape *aShape = [[TheShape alloc] init];
[aShape release];
```

should show the message, though. :/

There are two reasons I can see this not happening:

- You did something weird with either the `alloc`, `init` or `release` method (in which case, post your code);
- You run in a garbage-collected environment and `dealloc` will simply never be called (it's `finalize` you should use in this case). Though I don't see why `+new` then `release` would give the expected results then.

Comment: `-init` does not imply ownership. On the other hand, methods whose names contain `alloc` or `new` do.

Comment: Though I understand what Bavarious says (CAN=ownership), I'm not sure what he's referencing in your original post that you... oh, nevermind. I just clicked the revisions link. Got it. Thanks, guys!